# Formarray slow rendering while loading large data in angular 6

Tags: angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, formarray

I am using angular 6. In that I am loading dynamic form using formarray.

Formarray contains more than 100rows of drop-down box. While loading large data it hangs the browser it takes more time to render the data.

That 100row drop-down contains state and city list.

While user editing the I have to show the selected state and city in rendered drop-down.

Is there any way to increase the performance of formarray data rendering.

Component.html

```
 <Form [formgroup]="invest">
 <Div formArrayName="addinvest">
  <div *ngFor="let addinvest of invest.controls.addinvest.controls;let I= index>
   <div [formGroupName]="i">
    <select fromControlName="state">
     <option *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="state">{{state}}</option>
    </Select>
    <select fromControlName="state">
     <option *ngFor="let city of cities" [value]="city">{{city}}. 
  </option>
    </Select>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </form>
```

Component.ts

```
setStateControl(){
let control=<FormArray>this.invest.controls.addinvest;
This.statelist.foreach(x=> {
  Control.push(this.fb.group({
    state: x.state,
    City: x.city
  })
 }
```

Before that I have loaded all drop-down list. While user editing the from I have to show corresponding values in drop-down

Note: Above code snippet is sample. May it contains some spelling mistake.

Comment: Post your component ts and html files to provide more information

Comment: in order to find root cause- please add more details, This.statelist <== how many items there? - how do you know the rendering is slow?  - please use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now and let us know the timing here.